# Error connecting Json file to MySQL database using pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, json, pymysql

[image: picture of the database]

```
import pymysql
import json

json_data = open("data_chart.json").read()
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)

connection = pymysql.connect(host='', user='=',
                             password='=', database='=')

cursor = connection.cursor()

for item in json_obj:

    Current_Fridge_Temp = item.get("Current Fridge Temperature")
    Target_Fridge_Temp = item.get("Target Fridge Temperature")
    Current_Freezer_Temp = item.get("Current Freezer Temperature")
    Target_Freezer_Temp = item.get("Target Freezer Temperature")
    E_Use = item.get("Energy Use")
    Fridge_Last_On = item.get("Fridge Last On Time")
    Fridge_Last_Off = item.get("Fridge Last Off Time")
    Freezer_Last_On = item.get("Freezer Last On Time")
    Freezer_Last_Off = item.get("Freezer Last Off Time")

    cursor.execute("insert into refrigerator_id(Current Fridge Temperature, Target Fridge Temperature, "
                   "Current Freezer Temperature, Target Freezer Temperature, Energy Use, Fridge Last On Time, "
                   "Fridge Last Off Time, Freezer Last On Time, Freezer Last Off Time) "
                   "VALUES(%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d)", (Current_Fridge_Temp, Target_Fridge_Temp, Current_Freezer_Temp,
                                                         Target_Freezer_Temp, E_Use, Fridge_Last_On, Fridge_Last_Off,
                                                         Freezer_Last_On, Freezer_Last_Off))
 
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Getting these traceback errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ConnectionTest.py", line 24, in <module>
    cursor.execute("insert into refrigerator_id(Current Fridge Temperature, Target Fridge Temperature, "
  File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 146, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 125, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

I tried changing the VALUES to %s but that didn't work.

Comment: How exactly "didn't" changing it to `%s` work?

Comment: It gave me errors with raise errorclass(errno, errval), in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data), in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()

Comment: That doesn’t help, give us the full error message. The correct placeholder for SQL statements *is* `%s`.

Comment: File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 125, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: the issue is with the cursor.execute() because I have tested the connection and file separately.

Comment: Replace all occurrences of `%d` with `%s` in your code. Make sure and double check that you've replaced all of them. Then it should work.

Comment: @pts I changed all occurrences to %s still running into line 24, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO refrigerator_id LIMIT 100 (Current Fridge Temperature, Target Fridge Temperature, Current Freezer Temperature,.... error line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()

Comment: @sam: This is not the full error message, the informative parts are missing. Please copy-paste the full output of the program, including the full error message, formatted properly, to the question.

Comment: It's unlikely that *Current Fridge Temperature* is the actual MySQL column name, because of the spaces. What was the `CREATE TABLE` command? How was the column name spelled there? Was it quoted? If yes, it should be quoted (escaped) in `INSERT INTO` as well: `\`Current Fridge Temperature\``

Comment: @pts File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)File "/Users/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()File

Comment: @pts SELECT * FROM refrigerator_id LIMIT 100; ALTER TABLE
 refrigerator_id CHANGE refrigerator_id refrigerator_id int(11) NOT NULL;ALTER TABLE
 refrigerator_id CHANGE current_fridge_temperature current_fridge_temperature int(11);ALTER TABLE
 refrigerator_id CHANGE target_fridge_temperature target_fridge_temperature int(11);

Comment: @sam: In `INSERT INTO`, you have to use `current_fridge_temperature` instead of `Current Fridge Temperature` etc., because the former is the actual column name.

Comment: @sam: Please copy-paste the entire error message to the question. Don't truncate it!

Comment: @pts I changed all the column names as you said and still getting the same error   File "/Users/shyam/PycharmProjects/cs411w/ConnectionTest.py", line 24, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO refrigerator_id LIMIT 100 (Current_Fridge_Temperature, Target_Fridge_Temperature, "

Comment: convert all items from json to int as json only returns strings

Comment: @sam: You are still posting the truncated, useless error message, despite having been asked 3 times (this is number 4) to post the full error message. We are unable to help if we don't see the full error message. Please copy-paste the full output of the program, including the full error message, formatted properly, by editing the question. Don't try posting the error message as a comment, it will get truncated.

Comment: To help debugging, please replace `cursor.execute(...)` with `print((...))` (with double parentheses), and copy-paste the program's output by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Jsons elemnts  are all strings, so you need to convert them into integers before running your query

```
Current_Fridge_Temp = int(item.get("Current Fridge Temperature")))
Target_Fridge_Temp = int(item.get("Target Fridge Temperature"))
Current_Freezer_Temp = int(item.get("Current Freezer Temperature"))
Target_Freezer_Temp = int(item.get("Target Freezer Temperature"))
E_Use = int(item.get("Energy Use"))
Fridge_Last_On = item.get("Fridge Last On Time")
Fridge_Last_Off = item.get("Fridge Last Off Time")
Freezer_Last_On = item.get("Freezer Last On Time")
Freezer_Last_Off = item.get("Freezer Last Off Time")
```

Comment: Thank you, this was able to work but getting a error on line 19 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/cConnectionTest.py", line 19, in <module>
    Fridge_Last_On = int(item.get("Fridge Last On Time"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10:59:5'

Comment: {
        "Current Fridge Temperature": 30,
        "Target Fridge Temperature": 38,
        "Current Freezer Temperature": 9,
        "Target Freezer Temperature": 2,
        "Energy Use": 265,
        "Fridge Last On Time": "7:10:8",
        "Fridge Last Off Time": "23:12:36",
        "Freezer Last On Time": "20:9:45",
        "Freezer Last Off Time": "7:55:12"
    }

Comment: had you posted a text maybe i had looked closer you need only to convert the integer. so i chahged my answer